# Inserting the count value of records into database table using LINQtoSQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, record-count

I have a database table called *AllCustomersHistoryOfRecords* which is table with history of all the records bought by all the users who visit my application/website. There is another table called *Components* which just enlists all the components available (for downloading) from my website. Now i want to count all the records available in *AllCustomersHistoryOfRecords* and update the count in field *Total_Downloads* of *Components* table. Here is what i'm doing to accomplish this:

Which is primarily counting the occurences of each record in *AllCustomersHistoryOfRecords* table.

```
var componentCount = from c in db.Components
                                 join cr in db.AllCustomersHistoryOfRecords
                                 on c.Component_Name equals cr.Software_Title into temporary
                                 select temporary.Count();
```

And this is the code i'm using to insert the data into *Components* table:

```
Component comp = new Component { Total_Downloads = componentCount};
db.Components.InsertOnSubmit(comp);
```

But the problem is i'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<int>' to 'int?'
```

How can i solve this problem ? Please Help me out!!

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the componentCount field is a nullable field?

If this is the case you need to cast componentCount to a nullable int and also return a result set from the linq query rather than an IQueryable.

```
    var componentCount = (from c in db.Components
                                     join cr in db.AllCustomersHistoryOfRecords
                                     on c.Component_Name equals cr.Software_Title into temporary
                                     select c).Count();
    Component comp = new Component { Total_Downloads = (int?)componentCount};
    db.Components.InsertOnSubmit(comp);
```

**EDIT** Looping through components and updating counts

You'll need to replace c.ComponenetId and comp.ComponentId with what ever is the primary key on the component table/object. There may be some minor issues as I havent run this but it should give you a good idea of how to achieve what you are after.

```
var components = (from c in db.components select c).ToList();
foreach(var comp in components)
{
    var componentCount = (from c in db.Components
                         join cr in db.AllCustomersHistoryOfRecords
                         on c.Component_Name equals cr.Software_Title into temporary
                         where c.ComponentId == comp.ComponentId
                         select c).Count();
    comp.Total_Downloads = (int?)componentCount;                
}
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: @Gavin this is the error i'm getting if i use your code: Cannot convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<int>' to 'int?'

Comment: @Gavin My query is wrong, it is just getting all the records count not the specific count for occurences of each record in the AllCustomersHistoryOfRecords table

Comment: So you want an individual count for each component? In which case you probably shouldnt be creating a new component but updating the existing is that right?

Comment: @Gavin yes exactly thats right !! How can i go forward with that ? Help me out !!

Comment: This is how i changed the query to retrieve the count of each record present in the AllCustomersHistoryOfRecords table: var componentCount = (from c in db.Components
                                      join cr in db.CustomersRecords
                                          on c.Component_Name equals cr.Software_Title into temporary
                                      select new{ Total_Items_Bought = temporary.Count()});

Comment: @Gavin I'm trying and i will come back to you as soon i customize it to my application

Comment: @gavin It works after little bit of tweaking but i borrowed your idea (which was fantastic) !! thanks a lot for your immediate feedback. Appreciate it !! Have a nice day !!

Answer (score 1):

Should there not be a set of parentheses there?

```
var componentCount = (from c in db.Components
                             join cr in db.AllCustomersHistoryOfRecords
                             on c.Component_Name equals cr.Software_Title into temporary
                             select temporary).Count();
```

EDIT:
If I understand correctly, you are trying to get the sum all all the counts? 
If correct then how about this:

```
var componentCount = (from c in db.Components
                             join cr in db.AllCustomersHistoryOfRecords
                             on c.Component_Name equals cr.Software_Title into temporary
                             select temporary.Count()).Sum();
```

If not, then can you please describe what you want to do?

Comment: i got help from gavin thanks a lot for your feedback. Appreciate it !!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling .First() on your query so the result is not returned as an IQuerable. This is also stated in this post.

[Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'int?'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575238/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-linq-iqueryableint-to-int)